# Refactor functions so they can be used within a CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, refactoring

I have a `parent` and `child` table as following:

```
create table parent
(
  identifier serial primary key,
  name text
);
create table child
(
  identifier serial primary key,
  name text, parent_identifier integer references parent
);
```

I created two utility functions to format a `parent` and `child` row to a JSON object:

```
create function format(child) returns json
  as $$
  select json_build_object('identifier', $1.identifier, 'name', $1.name)
  $$ language sql stable;

create function format(parent) returns json
  as $$
  select json_build_object('identifier', $1.identifier, 'name', $1.name, 
                           'children', array(select format(child) from child where parent_identifier = $1.identifier))
  $$ language sql stable;
```

Let's test this:

```
insert into parent(name) values('first parent');
insert into parent(name) values('second parent');

insert into child(name, parent_identifier) values('first child first parent', (select identifier from parent where name = 'first parent'));
insert into child(name, parent_identifier) values('second child first parent', (select identifier from parent where name = 'first parent'));
insert into child(name, parent_identifier) values('first child second parent', (select identifier from parent where name = 'second parent'));

select format(parent) from parent;
```

This returns the following JSON objects:

```
{
   "identifier":5,
   "name":"first parent",
   "children":[
      {
        "identifier":7,
        "name":"first child first parent"
      },
      {
        "identifier":8,
        "name":"second child first parent"
      }
   ]
}
{
   "identifier":6,
   "name":"second parent",
   "children":[
      {
        "identifier":9,
        "name":"first child second parent"
      }
   ]
}
```

Great! Though, this has one big problem: if another transaction does some changes in between our `insert` and `select` queries, the `select` query does exactly return what we just inserted. We can fix this by setting the transaction isolation level to `repeatable read`, but that has its performance costs and other drawbacks (we might have to retry).

So I thought about rewriting the queries above in one single CTE. If I am not mistaken, this will not suffer from such concurrency issues. I started as following:

```
with
parents as
(
  insert into parent(name)
  select 'first parent'
  union all
  select 'second parent'
  returning parent.identifier, parent.name
),
children as
(
  insert into child(name, parent_identifier)
  select 'first child first parent', identifier from parents where name = 'first parent'
  union all
  select 'second child first parent', identifier from parents where name = 'first parent'
  union all
  select 'first child second parent', identifier from parents where name = 'second parent'
)
select format(parents::parent) from parents;
```

This does not work as expected. It returns the following JSON objects:

```
{
   "identifier":7,
   "name":"first parent",
   "children":[]
}
{
   "identifier":8,
   "name":"second parent",
   "children":[]
}
```

As you can see, there are no children included. After some reading, I understand what is going on. The CTE works on a snapshot created right before when the query was started. In `format(parent)`, we are doing `select format(child) from child where parent_identifier = $1.identifier)`, but that does not yield any child rows, because the child rows are not in the snapshot. So my question is not about this, as I understand this.

Of course, I could easily fix this if I simple do the `json_build_object` stuff, exactly the same as in the `format` functions, in the main query, but then I am duplicating code. I am using these `format` functions also in other queries, unrelated to this question. Ideally, I want to avoid code duplication in my solution. So I would like to keep using them and probably need to refactor them first so they can be used in the scenario in this question.

I'm quite stuck now. I really would like to continue with the CTE (so I can avoid having to set the transaction isolation level to `repeatable read`), but I cannot find a way to re-factor the `format(parent)` and `format(child)` functions and/or the CTE so I don't end up with code duplicates all over the place. Is there a smart soul on SO with some clever ideas?

Note that I am using PostgreSQL 10.1. Please find a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a251d/2

**update regarding Laurenz Albe's answer**

Context: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48152380/1

In the question above, I was indeed simplifying my situation. Let me explain the real scenario more closely, without going into too much details which will be confusing.

In the scenario, the user is providing data (= `parents` and their corresponding `children`) for a certain date range, for example the month January 2018. Also, I am not just doing inserts, I am actually doing upserts and deletes of orphaned rows. So, the scenario is simple: the client is replacing all data for a given date range.

If I then do `select format(parent) from parent where <parent is in date range as provided>` after the upserts and deletes, some other client might have altered an overlapping date range in between. In that case, I am returning different results as provided by the client, which might introduce bugs if the clients are not properly implemented. Hence, that's why I believe the inserts and select need be part of the same transaction with transaction isolation level set to `repeatable read`.

But then, I started thinking about one single, fat CTE, hence my question.

I hope this clarifies the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed correctly, you cannot see rows modified in the CTE in the main `SELECT`. This [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements
>   in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is
>   unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot
>   (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's
>   effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   `RETURNING` data is the only way to communicate changes between different
>   `WITH` sub-statements and the main query.

So you should use `RETURNING`.

I guess the simplest way would be not to use a function, but to perform `json_build_object` in the main query and have it operate on the CTEs `parents` and `children`.

Comment: Reading my question again, I understand why you get that impression. Please give me some time to add an update to my question, so this will make things more clear. Thank you very much for your answer so far though, it already gave me some insights.

Comment: I added some additional information. Now, I am not sure if your remark that only `select format(parent) from parent` could be run in a single transaction, is valid. During the select, I only want to exactly see what I just did in the previous queries. Therefore I think the whole logic should be in one single transaction with `repeatable read`. But then, one single, fat CTE came to my mind...

Comment: As a side note, I also don't understand what you gain with executing a single `select` query in a `repeatable read` transaction versus a `read committed` transaction. Isn't a single `select` query guaranteed to be consistent anyway, regardless of the isolation level? I asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152797/what-is-the-difference-in-executing-a-single-select-query-in-read-committed-vers

Comment: If the function contains several `SELECT`s, they'll see different snapshots of the database with `READ COMMITTED`.

Comment: Oh, got you. In my case, I am just doing one single `SELECT`.

Comment: So this brings me back to my initial question, if I am not mistaken: I can run the whole logic in one single `repeatable read` transaction or do some clever things in a CTE?

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to do `json_build_object` in the main query: that's exactly what I like to avoid. If I do that, I am not using the `format` functions anymore. I am using these `format` functions also in other queries. So, if I start doing `json_build_object` in the main query, I am actually duplicating code. I think that was not clear in my question (TIL: I suck at asking questions.) I updated my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Then I guess there won't be anything better than using `REPEATABLE READ` for the whole thing and retry the transaction on error.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I thought there was a clever way to avoid the overhead of the `REPEATABLE READ`, alas. Thanks for your thoughts!