# What is the difference in executing a single select query in read committed versus repeatable read transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

This question is a little spin-off from [Refactor functions so they can be used within a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151238/refactor-functions-so-they-can-be-used-within-a-cte).

The question is simple: is there a different in executing a `SELECT` query in a `READ COMMITTED` versus a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction? We assume that no other queries (even 'SELECT' queries) are done in the transaction. So the transaction is only executing one single `SELECT` query.

Comment: For a **single** query, no there is no difference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, until commit is not done `repeatable read` may look more resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally there won't be a difference for a single `SELECT` statement.

The exception is if the `SELECT` statement calls user defined functions that themselves issue multiple SQL statements.

In this case, `REPEATABLE READ` will make all these SQL statements share a single snapshot of the database, while `READ COMMITTED` will cause each SQL statement to see a different state of the database.