# How to execute two queries separately?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a functions which inserts some rows in table `my_table` and return their identifier:

```
create function step_1() returns setof uuid as
$$
    insert into my_table(...) values(...) returning identifier;
$$
language sql volatile;
```

Now I want to use this function in another select query:

```
create function step_2() returns setof my_table as
$$
    select *
    from   my_table
    where  identifier in(select * from step_1());
$$
language sql volatile;
```

The problem here is that `step_1()` is never executed, because initially `my_table` does not consist any rows, so PostgreSQL is optimizing to not execute `select * from step_1()`.

I think I need two things:

- `step_1()` should always be executed, regardless of the contents of `my_table`.
- `step_1()` should be executed as a separate query/context, so when `step_2()` is doing the `select`, it will actually see the inserted rows. The inserted rows should be present in the snapshot on which `step_2()` is executing.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may execute `step_1()` with a `FOR LOOP` in plpgsql, and do a `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE identifier = loop_item`. `loop_item`is the identifier from the current loop execution. I think your second requirement is unsolvable, because stored functions run always inside of a transaction. They doesn't _see_ modifications from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table my_table (identifier uuid)
;
create function step_1() returns setof uuid as $$
    insert into my_table (identifier) values (gen_random_uuid())
    returning identifier;
$$ language sql volatile
;
create or replace function step_2() returns setof my_table as $$
    declare a_identifier uuid[];
    begin
    a_identifier := (
        select array_agg(identifier)
        from step_1() s (identifier)
    )
    ;
    return query
    select *
    from my_table
    where identifier = any (a_identifier)
    ;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile
;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is not what I want though, but my question was probably misleading. I am returning a set of identifiers and I want to select from there on. In my real scenario, the select query is more complicated. Context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151238/refactor-functions-so-they-can-be-used-within-a-cte

Comment: @LeslyO Can you use `plpgsql`?

Comment: Yes, I could. I am having problems figuring this out, either in `sql` or `plpgsql`.

Comment: @LeslyO Edited with `plpgsql`

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! I did not think about materializing the identifiers first. I kept trying with subquery, CTE, ... So this is kinda impossible without materializing the identifiers first I suppose? I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @LeslyO The same snapshot of the data is seen everywhere inside a command. The modified table can't be retrieved.